# Tomcat Docker Container cannot be accessed by multiple users

Tags: docker, tomcat, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have an AWS cluster running my Docker stack, which includes a Tomcat container deploying my web app. I can access the latter using any web browser (tried firefox, chrome and safari) and everything works fine. However, if my colleague accesses it at the same time as I do then one of us will get a 'page cannot be displayed', meaning that it accepts only one user at a time.

This only happens with my Docker Tomcat containers: i) none of my web apps have this problem without Docker; ii) with Docker, only those deployed with Tomcat have this problem.

A filtered example of one of my Tomcat containers in compose.yml file:

```
...

mycontainer:
    image: imageregistry:443/dummy/mycontainer
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    links:
      - someOtherApp
    depends_on:
      - someOtherApp
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    networks:
      mylan:
        aliases:
          - mycontainer

...
```

Does anyone have any idea why this happens? Thank you so much for your attention.